# How to create point symbols with smooth color gradient fill and associated legend?

Tags: qgis, legend, heat-map, qgis-2.16

I like the feature heatmap as a layer style, but it doesn't have any symbolism in the legend at the compose manager. So I took a print screen from a characteristic part of the heatmap and now I am pasting it in the legend near the Text of the heatmap reference. But for every new project I have to make the same job, or move it if I move the legend...is there a simpler way for it?

[image: example]

I am using heatmap for stand alone trees instead of svg symbols or simple points. I think it makes the map prettier. So the heatmap has small radius circles and white area. A green square is not what I am looking for. Mostly I made this question, if there is somewhere a parameter for editing the point layer with the heatmap style and I haven't seen it.

Answer (score 4):

*edit:* 
Due to question was improved here is exact solution:

1. Go to symbology properties of point layer **Layer Properties -> Style**
2. In the symbol layer list choose Simple marker and change the **Symbol layer type** from Sipmle marker to **Filled marker**

[image]

3. Same way in the properites of Simple fill change **Symbol layer type** from Simple fill to **Shapeburst fill** and set colors or color ramp that you want

[image]

Result:

[image]

*old answer:*
Using **Heatmap plugin** you can generate new heatmap raster file. Use this raster itself for output map or you can use only symbology from this raster for specific radius.

Heatmap plugin:

[image: Heatmap plugin]

Heatmap plugin output raster:

[image: Heatmap plugin output raster]

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using circular symbols then the draw effects in the style manager?

You can create a similar effect adding in an inner glow to your tree points and adding modifying the gradient to suit what you're after. Here is an example; simply modify the spread, blur radius and color ramp to how you want it to look like.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you using **Heatmap plugin** you can create the result raster.

[image]
.

And in the composer you can add the Legend.

[image]

And for save your layer or load style in other raster:

[image]

Comment: I am using heatmap for stand alone trees instead of svg symbols or simple points. I think it makes the map prettier. So the heatmap has small radius circles and white area. A green square is not what I am looking for. Mostly I made this question, if there is somewhere a parameter for editing the point layer with the heatmap style and I haven't seen it.

Comment: Of course it is a very useful tip, but I like the merging of the circles the algorithm does, instead of the point layers, even if they have been edited. I think heatmap gives a more realistic view if you have 2-3 trees one near the other (1-2m dist.). It will give a bushy view,instead of 3 circles who have a standard radius.